# How to Retrieve the Identity column value in an insert trigger SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables that are identical except one has an identity column and the other doesn't. Instead the second table uses the value of the identity column from the first table. I thought I would insert into the second table as a trigger when a record is inserted into the first table. I cannot seem to get syntax right.

Null is being returned from the identity column @EDVisitId.

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[trgInserterrEDVisitOriginal] ON [dbo].[errEDVisit]
AFTER INSERT
AS


--Name:  Bob Avallone
--Date:  6-15-2017
--
--  The purpose of this trigger is to insert a record into errEDVisitOriginal
--  whenever a new errEDVisit is inserted.

--XXXXXXXXXX



    declare @EDVisitId  int
    declare @SubmissionControlID INT


Select  @EDVisitId = EDVisitID from inserted
SELECT @SubmissionControlID = SubmissionControlID  from Inserted


  Begin

Insert Into errEDVisitOriginal (EDVisitId, SubmissionControlID)

VALUES (@EDVisitId, @SubmissionControlID )



End
```

Comment: Your trigger has a MAJOR flaw!!! It assumes there will only ever be a single row in inserted. Triggers in sql server fire once per operation. As such triggers need to be set based and not scalar based.

Comment: Instead of doing this in a trigger you should have an insert procedure. In that procedure you would want to utilize the OUTPUT clause so you can capture ALL newly inserted identity values.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for all the suggestions. I abandoned the idea of a trigger. Instead I simply insert the new records from the first table into the second one. See below.

```
Insert errEDVisitOriginal(EdVisitId, SubmissionControlID)
    Select EdVisitId,  SubmissionControlID 
    from errEDVisit where SubmissionControlID = @SubmissionControlID
```

Answer (score 0):

you just need scope_identity()

Select  @EDVisitId = scope_identity()

Comment: This gets the identity but it is perpetuating the flawed nature of the trigger.

Comment: @SeanLange What is the flaw yo are referring to?  The only thing you say is a problem in your post is "Null is being returned from the identity column @EDVisitId."  When you set the ID with scope_identity(), what is the problem then?

Comment: Because using scalar variables like this in a trigger assumes there is ever only 1 row inserted. That is not how triggers work in sql server. Triggers need to be set based. If you stick with scalar values in a trigger you have to add a loop. Ugh!!

Answer (score 0):

You can use SCOPE_IDENTITY to get the last inserted id from the first table put it into a variable then insert into the second table.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/scope-identity-transact-sql

Comment: Using variables like this in a trigger is not a good approach when multiple rows get inserted.

Comment: I didn't realised he's using it on a trigger. I would do it on the stored procedure that do the insert instead of the trigger.

Answer (score 0):

Though the decision to duplicate information intentionally is dubious, you are vastly over-thinking the code. Just:

```
if exists (select * from inserted)
insert dbo.errEDVisitOriginal (EDVisitId, SubmissionControlID)
select EDVisitId, SubmissionControlID from inserted;
```